# NSProgressIndicator UI not update

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface, nsprogressindicator

I'm trying to update manually the doubleValue of `NSProgressIndicator` but the UI of the fill progress bar is stay on minimum.
What am I doing wrong?
On the log the values are updated

```
//Add progress-bar
    var hudSlider = NSProgressIndicator(frame: NSRect(x: view.frame.midX, y: view.frame.midY, width: 100, height: 40))
    hudSlider.minValue = 0.0
    hudSlider.maxValue = 100.0
    hudSlider.doubleValue = 50.0
    view.addSubview(hudSlider, positioned: .above, relativeTo: nil)
```

[image: UI of NSProgressIndicator]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with set `isIndeterminate` property to false

```
hudSlider.isIndeterminate = false
```